# Is using split declaration for char* array c99 compatible?

Tags: c, pointers, initialization

I've been using split declaration/assignments for string arrays in c like this:

```c
size_t arraysize = 2; // some arbitrary value - doesn't matter
char* str_array[arraysize];
int condition = 1; // some condition variable that is set earlier.
if (condition == 0) {
    str_array[0] = "hello";
    str_array[1] = "sir";
}
else {
    str_array[0] = "basketball";
    str_array[1] = "court";
}
```

or

```c
size_t arraysize = 2; // some arbitrary value - doesn't matter
char** str_array = malloc(sizeof(char*)*arraysize);
int condition = 1; // some condition variable that is set earlier.
if (condition == 0) {
    str_array[0] = "hello";
    str_array[1] = "sir";
}
else {
    str_array[0] = "basketball";
    str_array[1] = "court";
}
// free str_array somewhere down the line
```

for a while now, but someone just asked me "is that c99 compatible?", to which I had no good response.  The primary reason why I like to do things this way is because I may not be aware of the size of the strings I'm going to use when I initialize my pointer (the strings for the different condition variable values are different sizes).  Should I be concerned about this practice (aka is there a better way to accomplish the same thing) or does it not really matter?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "split declarations"? Using separate variable declaration and value assignment? What would be the alternative? You didn't specify in the question what exactly you want to accomplish, so it's difficult to tell if there is a better way. Is there a specific reason why you allocate space for 10 pointers but assign one of them only? Please [edit] your question to add clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> char* str_array[10];
> str_array[0] = "some string";
> ```

You realize you are storing the *address* of the first character of `"some string"` to `str_array[0]`; you are not storing the *string* `"some string"` to `str_array`.

And that is entirely valid *if* that's what you're trying to accomplish.  You can have a whole array of pointers to strings:

```
char *str_array[10];

str_array[0] = "some string";
str_array[1] = "some other string";
str_array[2] = "yet another string";
...
```

But each `str_array[i]` only stores the address of the string literal, not the string itself.

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`" and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

The expression `"some string"` has type `char [12]` (12-element array of `char`) - since it is not being used to initialize an array of character type in a declaration, it "decays" to an expression of type `char *` (pointer to `char`) and its value is the address of the first character `'s'`.

If you had written

```
char str_array[] = "some string"; // note type of str_array
```

then the *contents* of `"some string"` would be copied to `str_array` (whose size would be computed from the length of the initializer).

Comment: yes I understand that I am pointing to the first character of "some string" and that is the intended behaviour.  I do not see a problem with this approach, but I was asked if it was "C99-compatible" and, not being heavily immersed in C nor using it all the time and being aware of the ins and outs of C standards, I did not know the answer to his question.

Comment: @Mike - then what you are doing is perfectly fine, regardless of the version of C in use.  Although I would suggest you declare the pointer as `const char *` so the compiler will yell at you if you accidentally try to update the string literal.